# StackOverflowError using parse.com library

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, stack-overflow

In my android app i am using parse library,and am getting StackOverflowError.No particular trigger i could find for it.Happens randomly.Sometimes does,Sometimes doesn't.

Here is my stack trace.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
        at java.security.MessageDigestSpi.<init>(MessageDigestSpi.java:30)
        at java.security.MessageDigest.<init>(MessageDigest.java:69)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.<init>(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:53)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.<init>(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:25)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK$MD5.<init>(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:119)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:998)
        at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:155)
        at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:91)
        at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.getDigest(DigestUtils.java:88)
        at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.getMd5Digest(DigestUtils.java:102)
        at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(DigestUtils.java:166)
        at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(DigestUtils.java:191)
        at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(DigestUtils.java:227)
        at com.parse.ParseJSONCacheItem.<init>(ParseJSONCacheItem.java:16)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.checkForChangesToMutableContainer(ParseObject.java:1074)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.checkForChangesToMutableContainers(ParseObject.java:1096)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:997)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.isDirty(ParseUser.java:95)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.isDirty(ParseUser.java:95)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.isDirty(ParseUser.java:95)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.isDirty(ParseUser.java:95)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
```

As i said,tried hard but couldn't find what triggers it.any help from parsers would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Add some logs/breakpoints to your code to find at which point the error manifests. The stack trace here is not helpful without any code. StackOverflowErrors are often caused by recursive calls to a method that do not break/terminate; do you have any recursively called methods in your code?

Comment: Well i know what it is.and have tried logs etc,but it happens as soon as the app opens.None of my code is called as clear from the stack trace. Anyways i am doing some head scratching. Will post when i find something. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i was checking for anonymous account link right after the user signed up,while in the background a save task was going on with the current user. That made parse library go crazy, So what i did was use a callback for save and do all the work after save was completed.